# how to resolve a HTTP 400 Bad Request error?

Tags: node.js, angular, http, express

I have developed an Angular4 application that does HTTP requests to a nodeJS server application. 
An URL works for http.get() but the same URL for http.put() or http.post() throws HTTP 400  Bad Request error.
How is this possible??

```
let temp=this._http.post("http://localhost:4200/medicine/edit/"
+String(updatedEmployee.id),updatedEmployee.id);
```

[angular code link]codeshare.io/5wlnLR

[express route code] codeshare.io/G8npdD

Comment: add node & express route code.

Comment: [angular code link]https://codeshare.io/5wlnLR
[express route code] https://codeshare.io/G8npdD

Comment: add those in question.

Comment: Check your server logs.

Comment: Server logs also provide the same redundant information. 400 Bad request.